# How can I destructure an array of arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays. Each nested array contain objects, however it may contain array of objects. For example:

```
let arr=[[{a:1}],[{b:2}, [{c:3}, {d:4}]]]
```

I want to create an array which will contain only the objects destructuring all the arrays. I tried

```
arr.reduce((a,b) => [...a,...b], [])
```

but what am I getting is :

```
[{a:1}, {b:2}, [{c:3},{d:4}]]
```

which is not what I want.
I want to get:

```
 [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}, {d:4}]
```

Comment: Do you have a *concrete* shape of the data? If not, you can't dynamically destructure. You are better off just flattening the array.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: @Pointy is correct, he should add this as an answer as this answers the question, so it can be marked as correct.. Also, the reason this question is being downvoted is what you are requesting, and destructuring are 2 completely different things.

Comment: `.flat()` isn't implemented in some browsers, so you should maybe follow the alternatives the MDN article Pointy linked to provides.

Comment: @sgarcia.dev I'm pretty sure it's what the OP wants; I was looking for a duplicate because I could swear this came up just a few days ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should consider using the [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method.

```js
console.log( [[{a:1}],[{b:2}, [{c:3}, {d:4}]]].flat() )
```

You'll notice the above example only flattens one level. This is because the `depth` parameter defaults to `1`. In our case, we need to flatten 2 levels, so we explicitly pass `2` to `.flat()`.

```js
console.log( [[{a:1}],[{b:2}, [{c:3}, {d:4}]]].flat(2) )
```

If you need it to go deeper still, you can increase this number. If you need it to handle any depth, use [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

```js
console.log( [[{a:1}],[{b:2}, [{c:3}, {d:4}]]].flat(Infinity) )
```

It is worth noting that as of the writing of this answer, `flat()` [is not supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-flat). However, most transpilers (such as Babel) will polyfill it and NodeJS 11+ supports it. The MDN documentation for `Array.flat()` has [alternatives that use vanilla Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternative).

Comment: if `flat()` is not supported, you can use `_.flatten()` from `loadash` library.